# Filtering the columns (not rows) of a DataFrame based on vertical (not horizontal) average or sum in PySpark or Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, average

```py
data = [[12, 112, 14],
        [120, 112, 114],
        [88, 92, 74],
        [17, 118, 133],
        [19, 19, 14],
        [11, 12, 14]]
columns = ['Subject_1', 'Subject_2', 'Subject_3']
dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
dataframe.show()
# +---------+---------+---------+
# |Subject_1|Subject_2|Subject_3|
# +---------+---------+---------+
# |       12|      112|       14|
# |      120|      112|      114|
# |       88|       92|       74|
# |       17|      118|      133|
# |       19|       19|       14|
# |       11|       12|       14|
# +---------+---------+---------+
```

Consider that a school only wants to publish the subjects where it performs best.

How to have a `DF2` such that `DF2` would only have a few columns from `dataframe` such that subjects where:

> average marks is greater than a threshold

> average marks is 75th percentile and above given there are too many subjects

> sort the columns ascending order of average score

PySpark and Pandas DataFrame are considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this dataframe...

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
data = [[12, 112, 14, 15, 100],
        [120, 112, 114, 17, 87],
        [88, 92, 74, 76, 11],
        [17, 118, 133, 99, 51],
        [19, 19, 14, 54, 48],
        [11, 12, 14, 75, 60]]
columns = ['Subject_1', 'Subject_2', 'Subject_3', 'Subject_4', 'Subject_5']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
```

this is how averages look like:

```py
df_avg = df.agg(*[F.avg(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
df_avg.show()
# +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
# |Subject_1|Subject_2|Subject_3|Subject_4|Subject_5|
# +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
# |     44.5|     77.5|     60.5|     56.0|     59.5|
# +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

> sort the columns ascending order of average score

```py
d = df.agg(*[F.avg(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).head().asDict()
df = df.select(*sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=False))
df.show()
# +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
# |Subject_1|Subject_4|Subject_5|Subject_3|Subject_2|
# +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
# |       12|       15|      100|       14|      112|
# |      120|       17|       87|      114|      112|
# |       88|       76|       11|       74|       92|
# |       17|       99|       51|      133|      118|
# |       19|       54|       48|       14|       19|
# |       11|       75|       60|       14|       12|
# +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

> average marks is greater than a threshold

```py
threshold = 58
d = df.agg(*[F.avg(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).head().asDict()
df = df.select([k for k, v in d.items() if v >= threshold])
df.show()
# +---------+---------+---------+
# |Subject_2|Subject_3|Subject_5|
# +---------+---------+---------+
# |      112|       14|      100|
# |      112|      114|       87|
# |       92|       74|       11|
# |      118|      133|       51|
# |       19|       14|       48|
# |       12|       14|       60|
# +---------+---------+---------+
```

> average marks is 75th percentile and above

```py
import numpy as np

d = df.agg(*[F.avg(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).head().asDict()
perc_75 = np.percentile(list(d.values()), 75)
df = df.select([k for k, v in d.items() if v >= perc_75])
df.show()
# +---------+---------+
# |Subject_2|Subject_3|
# +---------+---------+
# |      112|       14|
# |      112|      114|
# |       92|       74|
# |      118|      133|
# |       19|       14|
# |       12|       14|
# +---------+---------+
```

**Pandas:**

> sort the columns ascending order of average score

```py
df[df.mean().sort_values(ascending=True).index]
```

> average marks is greater than a threshold

```py
threshold = 58
df[df.mean()[lambda x: x >= threshold].index]
```

> average marks is 75th percentile and above

```py
perc_75 = df.mean().quantile(.75)
df[df.mean()[lambda x: x >= perc_75].index]
```